# Case when to sum fields for different condition retrieves both results

Tags: oracle, query

I'm trying to sum fields based on condition but the query results display both results for both conditions. This is the query I'm using:

```
select 
  distinct project_id, 
  version, 
  phase, 
  fund_v, 
  source, 
  (total_match) total_match, 
  (total) total, 
  (prior_total) prior_total, 
  (total_beyond) total_beyond, 
  the_order 
from 
  (
    select 
      pds.project_id, 
      pds.version, 
      'SUBTOTAL' phase, 
      50 the_order, 
      pds.source fund_v, 
      source, 
      total_match, 
      nvl(
        (
          select 
            sum(
              envir + myrow + construc + ed + pse + con
            ) 
          from 
            fund_view 
          where 
            project_id = pds.project_id 
            and version = pds.version 
            and pds.source = source 
            and nvl(COMMENTS, 'Z') = nvl(cc, 'Z') 
            and to_number(
              replace(ffy, 'UNK', '')
            ) < to_number(
              substr(mtip_version, 1, 2)
            ) + 2000 + 1
        ), 
        0
      ) prior_total, 
      case when mtip_version = mtp.mtip_version 
      and mtp.admin_formal like 'MTP%' 
      and substr(mtip_version, 1, 2) = '15' then nvl (
        (
          select 
            sum(
              envir + myrow + construc + ed + pse + con
            ) 
          from 
            fund_view 
          where 
            project_id = pds.project_id 
            and version = pds.version 
            and pds.source = source 
            and nvl(COMMENTS, 'Z') = nvl(cc, 'Z') 
            and to_number(
              replace(ffy, 'UNK', '')
            ) >= to_number(
              substr(mtip_version, 1, 2)
            ) + 2000 + 4
        ), 
        0
      ) else nvl (
        (
          select 
            sum(
              envir + myrow + construc + ed + pse + con
            ) 
          from 
            fund_view 
          where 
            project_id = pds.project_id 
            and version = pds.version 
            and pds.source = source 
            and nvl(COMMENTS, 'Z') = nvl(cc, 'Z') 
            and to_number(
              replace(ffy, 'UNK', '')
            ) >= to_number(
              substr(mtip_version, 1, 2)
            ) + 2000 + 6
        ), 
        0
      ) end as total_beyond 
    from 
      x_proj_tmp p, 
      P_DISTINCT_S pds, 
      mtip mtp 
    where 
      p.project_id = pds.project_id 
      and p.version = pds.version
  ) p 
where 
  project_id = '3018884' 
order by 
  project_id, 
  version, 
  source, 
  the_order
```

For that specific project (3018884) all the ffy

```
FFY

ProjectId | Version | FFY       | Source |  Envir   |   MyRow   | Construc |   ED     |  Local F | Mtip_v | other fields are zero
3018884   |    1    | 2026.2040 | L Fund |  1295774 |  2426960    |  15-01    |
3018884   |    1    | 2015.2019 | F Fund |  6575000 |  6575000    |  15-01    |
3018884   |    1    | 2019.2025 | F Fund |  4027443 |  4900000    |  15-01    |
3018884   |    1    | 2015.2019 | L Fund |  1643750 |  1643750    |  15-01    |
3018884   |    1    | 2026.2040 | F Fund |  5183095 |  9707840    |  15-01    |
3018884   |    1    | 2019.2025 | L Fund |  1006861 |  1225000    |  15-01    |
```

For this specific project, all the mtip belongs to 15-xx so I need to get the sum of the fields but I got  both, basically I'm separating by prior and belong based on mtip = 2016 or 2021

Result:

```
3018884 1   SUBTOTAL    F Fund      36968378    36968378    13150000    14890935    50 (Not Expected)
3018884 1   SUBTOTAL    F Fund      36968378    36968378    13150000    23818378    50 (Expected)
3018884 1   SUBTOTAL    L Fund      9242095     9242095     3287500     3722734     50 (Not Expected)
3018884 1   SUBTOTAL    L Fund      9242095     9242095     3287500     5954595     50 (Expected)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

UPDATE:

I added the max to obtain the max on that values but still not working and returning both results.

```
(select max(
  case
    when mtip_version = mtp.mtip_version and mtp.admin_formal like 'MTP%' then 
      nvl((select 
sum(envir+myrow+construc+ed+pse+con) from fund_view where project_id=pds.project_id and version=pds.version and pds.source =source and nvl(comments,'Z') = nvl(cc,'Z')   and to_number( Replace(ffy,'UNK','') ) >= to_number( substr(mtip_version,1,2)) + 2000 + 4),0)
  else
      nvl((select sum(envir+myrow+construc+ed+pse+con) from fund_view where project_id=pds.project_id and version=pds.version and pds.source =source and nvl(comments,'Z') = nvl(cc,'Z')   and to_number( Replace(ffy,'UNK','') ) >= to_number( substr(mtip_version,1,2)) + 2000 + 6),0)
            end) 
        from fund_view where pds.project_id = project_id and pds.version = version and pds.source = source and nvl(COMMENTS,'Z') = nvl(cc,'Z')
        ) total_beyond,
```

not sure if I would need to perform on other way or this approach is not correct, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Here is the fiddle, I had to remove some dependencies but the main issue is there http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/979bb/14 as you can see I get four rows but the expected are the higher values on total_beyond field one for F Fund and one for L Fund, seems like both sums are performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a cartesian join with mtip so joining with fund_view is ideally to resolve that problem. Here is the result query for any reference. Thanks for your help.

```
SELECT distinct project_id, version, '-' phase, fund_v, source, (total) total, (prior_total) prior_total, (total_beyond) total_beyond, the_order
from (
select     pds.project_id,
  pds.version,
  'SUBTOTAL' phase, 
  50 the_order,
  pds.source fund_v,
  pds.source,
  1000 as total,
  nvl((select sum(envir+myrow+construc+ed+pse+con) from fund_view where project_id=pds.project_id and version=pds.version and pds.source=source and trunc(to_number(replace(ffy,'UNK',''))) <= to_number(substr(mtip_version,1,2)) + 2000 + 1),0) prior_total
,case when 
    fv.mtip_version = mtp.mtip_version and mtp.admin_formal like 'MTP%' then
nvl((select sum(envir+myrow+construc+ed+pse+con) from fund_view where project_id=pds.project_id and version=pds.version and pds.source=source and trunc(to_number(replace(ffy,'UNK',''))) <= to_number(substr(mtip_version,1,2)) + 2000 + 4),0) 
else 
    nvl((select sum(envir+myrow+construc+ed+pse+con) from fund_view where project_id=pds.project_id and version=pds.version and pds.source=source and trunc(to_number(replace(ffy,'UNK',''))) <= to_number(substr(mtip_version,1,2)) + 2000 + 6),0)
end as total_beyond
from x_proj_tmp p, P_DISTINCT_S pds, mtip mtp,fund_view fv  
where p.project_id=pds.project_id and p.version=pds.version and fv.mtip_version=mtp.mtip_version and fv.PROJECT_ID=pds.PROJECT_ID and fv.version=pds.version and fv.source=pds.source
) p

where project_id = '3018884'
order by project_id,version, source, the_order
```

Answer (score 0):

The entire logic of the query is not quite clear to me but one thing is certain: you are not filtering out the output rows properly. Your query's top level WHERE clause only filters the rows on `project_id`:

```
where 
  project_id = '3018884'
```

The `p` derived table's WHERE clause only contains joining conditions:

```
    where 
      p.project_id = pds.project_id 
      and p.version = pds.version
```

Maybe they are supposed to filter out some rows too, but I doubt those conditions are sufficient. Besides, the derived table's FROM clause lists three tables:

```
    from 
      x_proj_tmp p, 
      P_DISTINCT_S pds, 
      mtip mtp
```

while the WHERE covers only two of them. That means the third table is effectively cross-joined to the other two. Perhaps that is what is causing redundant rows? At the very least it may be a contributing factor.

My advice would be to get the row count right before getting the SUM results. Get rid of the subqueries in the `nvl` expressions, because I suspect they may be distracting you. Try to achieve the correct number of rows in the output that way. Make sure they are the right rows too, of course (minus the aggregations). Only then try adding the aggregations back to get the final result set.

Comment: I agree, rewriting with ANSI joins becomes: `  from x_proj_tmp p
  join P_DISTINCT_S pds
      ON p.project_id=pds.project_id 
     AND p.version=pds.version
  CROSS JOIN mtip mtp`